# TypeError in EventListener

Tags: javascript

The iterator is not getting recognized inside the eventListener. Please help me do the same.

```
var colors = ["rgb(255, 255, 0)","rgb(255, 0, 0)","rgb(255, 0, 255)","rgb(255, 120, 0)","rgb(255, 255, 255)","rgb(0, 0, 0)"];
const sq = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
const pick = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
for(var i = 0; i < sq.length; i++){
    sq[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    sq[i].addEventListener("click",() => {
        const clicked = this.style.backgroundColor;
        if(clicked === pick){
            alert("right");
        }else{
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323"
        }
    })
}
```

this or sq[i] is undefined inside eventlistener.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere using `forEach()`. You can see that I get both the element (elm) and the index (i). Inside the event listener you should refer to ´e.target´ as the element that was clicked.

So, in general. Try to get rid of for loops and referring to some index and use the event object in the event listener.

```js
var colors = ["rgb(255, 255, 0)", "rgb(255, 0, 0)", "rgb(255, 0, 255)", "rgb(255, 120, 0)", "rgb(255, 255, 255)", "rgb(0, 0, 0)"];
const sq = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
const pick = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";

sq.forEach((elm, i) => {
  elm.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  elm.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let clicked = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
    if (clicked === pick) {
      alert("right");
    } else {
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```